# How to use Chrome.Storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to save state of the extension. If it's on, the code will run on a specific website and if it's not, then it won't.

I have yet to understand how to do it, since i don't understand it fully.

This is the html of the checkbox (popup.html):

```html
<div class="onOff">
      <label class="switch">
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="saveValue" />
        <span class="slider round" id="theSwitch"></span>
      </label>

      <span id="onOroff">OFF</span>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code which just changes the color and text when you click on the button (bg color, on/off text.). This code is in **popup.js**:

```
    if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $("#onOroff").text("OFF");
      $(".slider").css({ "background-color": "#C75052" });
    } else {
      $("#onOroff").text("ON");
      $(".slider").css({ "background-color": "#50c878" });
    }
  });
```

Here you can see the extension:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Ip63ExB]

The code which deletes the ads is in contentEditor.js.

When you click on the extension and open it, Chrome sees it as just another page being opened, so when I turn the extension on (click on Off) and close the extension window, re-open it, it doesn't save that state.

I figure I need to save check/unchecked in a variable, pass that onto chrome.Storage and have chrome.storage save last version of the button.

Comment: Extensions consist of different contexts/components so it's important to understand where exactly this code runs. Add manifest.json and describe which files contain the posted code. As for using `chrome.storage` it's easy to find the existing examples using a site like https://www.google.com, here's a random example: [link](/a/38304863).

Comment: Jquery is in popup.js and html code is called popup.html. I have nothing in Background script and the code which edits the content on the page is in contentEditor.

I have hard time analyzing what I need to do. Do I write chrome.storage.set in popup.js? If so, how will background script read it? They're in different scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare storage permissions in the manifest

```
  {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
      "storage"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

and then use it like

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({yourValue: true}, function(){});
```

to set it, and to get it

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['yourValue'], function(result){
      // your value is in result.yourValue
});
```

The second parameter (function) is the callback, you need to use that to indicate what to do next with that data.

Comment: I have storage declared in persmissions.

Problem is: I have three scripts: Popup.js, contentEditor.js and background.js.
I don't get how to actually store the value of the checkbox (in which script) and then how to save it. Because I doubt background script can read css of popup.html.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring permissions in the manifest.json

```
    {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
      "storage"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

You can use the chrome.storage API in content, background and popup scripts.

```
if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
  $("#onOroff").text("OFF");
  chrome.storage.local.set({button: 'off'}, function() {
      console.log('Button state saved to off');
    });
  $(".slider").css({ "background-color": "#C75052" });
} else {
  $("#onOroff").text("ON");
  chrome.storage.local.set({button: 'on'}, function() {
      console.log('Button state saved to on');
    });
  $(".slider").css({ "background-color": "#50c878" });
}});
```

You would then have access to get the value in your background.js file by requesting it from chrome.storage.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['button'], function(result) {
      console.log('The button's state is currently ' + result.key);
    });
```